# How do I display specific string instead of model value in template using Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have an Ember route displaying an array of records. The model includes `status` like so:

```
status: DS.attr('number'),
```

The value of status will be returned as either: `-1`, `0` or `1`.

I have no problem displaying that value for each record in the template using handlebars: `{{modelName.status}}`. This way, the status for each record reflects as either: `-1`, `0`, `1`.

I would like to do the following:

> If the value of status is -1 display the string "Error".
>   If the value of status is 0 display the string "Completed".
>   If the value of status is 1 display the string "Pending".

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
status: DS.attr('number'),
statusLabel: function(){
  var statuses = ['Error', 'Completed', 'Pending'];
  return statuses[this.get('status') + 1];
}.property('status')
```

Then in your template:

```
{{modelName.statusLabel}}
```

Answer (score 1):

your question is not to much clear, for my options Ember trust helper will help you.
https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers.

you need to install Ember trust helper.

{{if (not-eq modelName.status -1 )}} Error

Answer (score 0):

A small addition to the first answer- let's say my needs are:

> If the value of status is -1 display the string "Error".
>    If the value of status is 0 display the string "Completed".
>    **If the value of status is anything greater than 0 display the string "Pending".**

```js
statusLabel: function() {
  var currentStatus = this.get('status');
  var statuses = ['Error', 'Completed', 'Pending'];
  if (currentStatus > 0) {
    return statuses[2];
  } else {
    return statuses[this.get('status') + 1];
  }
}.property('status'),
```